# How to align three boxes: two above each other, one on the righthandside of the two

Tags: html, css

I try to align three boxes (divs) in html5/ css3.  Two boxes are stacked above each other on the lefthandside, one should be on the righthandside of these two boxes, stretching over the entire height of the two left boxes.

Unfortunately I cannot align the right box with the other two.  It always appeary underneeth the left boxes, yet aligned with the right edge of the bracketing div.

These are the css-definitions I am using to position the boxes:

```
#leftTop {
    background-color: green;
    color: silver;
    width: 32%;
    height: 110px;
}

#leftBottom {
    background-color: red;
    color: yellow;
    width: 32%;
    height: 540px;
}

#rightAside {
    background-color: blue;
    color: pink;
    width: 60%;
    height: 650px;
    float:left;;
}
```

I tried several configurations with Display: inline-block, and the float command.  But unfortunalely nothing worked.

Does anybody have an idea? Your answers are highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/yb333/).

HTML:

```
<div id="leftWrapper">
   <div id="leftTop"></div>
   <div id="leftBottom"></div>
</div>
<div id="rightAside"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftWrapper {
    float:left;
    width: 32%;
    height: 650px;
}
#leftTop {
    background-color: green;
    color: silver;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
}

#leftBottom {
    background-color: red;
    color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 540px;
}

#rightAside {
    background-color: blue;
    color: pink;
    width: 60%;
    height: 650px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Sounds too easy to be true :-)

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to accept the answer so the question does not show up as unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#left
{
float:left;
 width: 32%;
}
#leftTop {
    background-color: green;
    color: silver;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
}

#leftBottom {
    background-color: red;
    color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 540px;
}

#rightAside {
    background-color: blue;
    color: pink;
    width: 60%;
    height: 650px;
    float:left;;
}
</style>
<div id="left">
<div id="leftTop"></div>
<div id="leftBottom"></div>
</div>
<div id="rightAside"></div>
```

Comment: That is an elegant solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

   <div class="box3">This is box 3</div>

   <div class="box1">This is box 1</div>

   <div class="box2">This is box 2</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #cccccc;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0000;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00ff00;
}

.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

Working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xmg6Z/